# My .htaccess is changed over and over and over

Tags: .htaccess, web

I hope you can help me, I have a website and constantly the .htaccess file is hacked to redirect to another page, every time I delete that file, when I check the file after 5 minutes, again the file is written to redirect to a page with malware, I changed passwords of sftp, the page itself and the database several times from different computers with windows and linux but this file is constantly changed in the main page and creating hacked .htaccess in the subdirectories, Why does this keep happening? HELP

The web page is hosted in Dreamhost.

Comment: I also changed the cmod to 755 of all folders.

Comment: What exactly do you host on that server? Do you use eg. PHP?

Comment: the web page is in Joomla, but i dont think could be a joomla problem couse these files are created even outside the joomla directory

Comment: Joomla has been known to have security issues for ages now. Try taking Joomla offline (and I don't mean deactivating it but eg. download the whole Joomla directory and completely delete it afterwards). And then try deleting .htaccess again. Sure, the CMS will be offline for a while - but I guess you'll have to set priorities now.

Answer (score 0):

If the permissions on your .htaccess file are set so that only you can modify it, then you will find one of the following:

- An entry in your FTP access log showing .htaccess being uploaded
- An entry in the control panel access log showing the .htaccess being edited
- An entry in your HTTP access log at the time that the modification happens (often a POST, but not necessarily).  This is often to a generalised backdoor process of some sort.
- A crontab entry that makes this modification

Additionally, you will find that your site was hacked somehow - e.g. insecure version of JCE editor, poor passwords, nonumber extensions, flash uploader, failure to update for known security problems, or similar.  It's all in the logs.  You will also find that there are a stack of little PHP files or an extra admin account which will let the attacker back once you sort out the obvious part of the problem.